# Is it possible to call Rust's struct fields directly from Ruby code without implementing extern "C" getter to the corresponding fields

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rust

I am thinking about writing a Ruby gem with Rust. Lets assume I want to create some structs in Rust which are returned to the Ruby code similar to the example [here](http://blog.skylight.io/bending-the-curve-writing-safe-fast-native-gems-with-rust/). While getting the Point struct to my Ruby code, I would like to call its attributes directly. Currently I would have to do something like that:

point.rb:

```
require "fiddle"
require "fiddle/import"

module RustPoint
  extend Fiddle::Importer

  dlload "./libmain.dylib"

  extern "Point* make_point(int, int)"
  extern "double get_distance(Point*, Point*)"
  extern "int y(Point*)"
  extern "int x(Point*)"

end
```

main.rs:

```
use std::num::pow;

pub struct Point { x: int, y: int }

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn make_point(x: int, y: int) -> Box<Point> {
  box Point { x: x, y: y }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn x(p: &Point) -> int {
  p.x
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn y(p: &Point) -> int {
  p.y
}
```

and use this in Ruby:

```
point = RustPoint::make_point(0, 42)
# To get x:
x = RustPoint::x(point)
```

to get an x value. I would prefer something like:

```
point = RustPoint::make_point(0, 42)
# To get x:
x = point.x
```

Does anyone know a library or a way to get this implemented easier. I think it would be much nicer if i wouldn't see a different regarding the point object from ruby side. i should not make a difference weather this is a C extension, a Ruby object or written in Rust.

Edit: I want the Rust code to behave like a native extension. So the returned struct should be callable from Ruby side similar to a C struct using ruby objects as values. Of course a library would be nessessary to handle the ruby objects in rust code.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the whole thing in a custom delegator:

```
class RustDelegator
  attr_accessor :__delegate_class__, :__delegate__

  def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block)
    __delegate_class__.public_send(method_name, *__rust_arguments__(arguments), &block)
  end

  def respond_to_missing(name, include_private = false)
    __delegate_class__.respond_to?(name, include_private)
  end

  private

  def __rust_arguments__(arguments)
    arguments.unshift(__delegate__)
  end
end

class Point < RustDelegator
  def initialize(x, y)
    self.__delegate_class__ = RustPoint
    self.__delegate__ = RustPoint::make_point(0, 42)
  end
end

p = Point.new(0, 42)
#=> #<Point:0x007fb4a4b5b9d0 @__delegate__=[0, 42], @__delegate_class__=RustPoint>

p.x
#=> 0

p.y
#=> 42
```

Comment: That would be a solution, but in that case I also just could implement a Point class in ruby using the extern c methods I mentioned. This would be faster. My question was more about some kind of native extension. So a rust struct given to ruby which natively behaves like a ruby struct.

Answer (score 0):

Rust provides a native C interface for `struct` as well. If you define your struct like this:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32
}
```

It will behave like the C struct

```
struct Point
{
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
}
```

You may then use it in Ruby like any other C struct.

I recommend using the fixed size int types rather than plain `int`, because you have no real guaranty Rust's `int` are the same size as C's `int`. If you really need to use it, you should probably use `libc::c_int`.